# Unable to add a if condition to the Procedure in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have a following procedure, but I want to add a condition to skip the transaction if my_status(From table myshop) is equivalent to 4. I want to add the if condition to the following code and tried but cannot do it. Since I'm a noob I'm 
stuck with this problem for quite long. I searched google and tried but cannot do it right. Some samples or hints would be great! I would love to hear from you!

```
BEGIN

INSERT 
INTO `donut`.`myshop` 
SELECT
 vs.id
 , vs.script_id
 , 0 as my_status
 , NULL as time_limit
 , NULL as time_limit2
 , NULL as time_limit3
 , NULL as items
FROM
 bread.reserve_table rt 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN baker.view_shops vs 
   ON rt.id = vs.id 
WHERE
 rt.start_date = CURRENT_DATE() 
 AND vs.start_date <> rt.start_date 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
id = values(id)
, script_id = values(script_id)
, my_status = values(my_status)
, time_limit = values(time_limit)
, time_limit2 = values(time_limit2)
, time_limit3 = values(time_limit3)
, items = values(items);


UPDATE
        baker.shops s
    SET
        start_date = (
            SELECT
                        start_date AS DATE
                FROM
                    bread.reserve_table
                WHERE
                    s.id = id LIMIT 1
        )
        ,end_date = (
            SELECT
                        end_date AS DATE
                FROM
                    bread.reserve_table
                WHERE
                    s.id = id LIMIT 1
        )
        ,random_id = 0
        ,random_flg = 0
    WHERE
        EXISTS (
            SELECT
                    1
                FROM
                    bread.reserve_table
                WHERE
                    s.id = bread.reserve_table.id
        AND
            bread.reserve_table.start_date =CURRENT_DATE()
        AND
            bread.reserve_table.start_date <> s.start_date
    );


END
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Provide a more detailed code example. Also read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your question and make it easier for people to answer.

Comment: Thank you Tony, I've updated the code. I wonder is to possible to send two sendinblue mail with php?